# How to pause time in iOS Programming

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my iOS program, I want a function to pause for 1 second. What code do I have to write to do this?

Comment: It's hard to answer this properly without knowing why you want to pause for a second. Unless you're careful - you'll just block the UI for a second which is a _very bad_ user experience.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use one of these: `sleep(1);` or `wait(1);`

Or you can use [`[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/sleepForTimeInterval:)

And there is also [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Or, put the rest of the tasks in a block and schedule it with `dispatch_after` ;)

Comment: Sleeping is almost certainly not a good idea. If Twinkle doesn't know how to use `sleep` already, I doubt that e is using a background thread. That means pausing the UI thread.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//Place code here});
```

sleep() and wait() are sometimes looked down upon but as long as you understand whats happening use it at your free will

Answer (score 2):

Newer to iOS are completion blocks. If you need to perform some action after a view controller is popped, for example, you could now use blocks. I recently used this method to dismiss a message compose view controller and then pop the current view controller if successful.

**Old way:**

```
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
// Use an NSThread or performSelector:withObject:afterDelay
```

**New Way:**

```
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
  if (result != MessageComposeResultCancelled){
    // If cancelled remain on current screen, else pop to parent view controller
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
}];
```